# How to set table height to height of container with vertical scroll?

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/awu1tzoj/

Is there a trick I'm missing to this? I want the table to also be limited to the height of the .panel-body.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.panel-body {
    height: 100px;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `overflow: auto` to the `.panel-body` class like so:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.panel-body {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Month</th>
          <th>Savings</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>January</td>
          <td>$100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>February</td>
          <td>$80</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>


  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awu1tzoj/2/